# Bullhorn Job list according to categories using REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I am setting up Bullhorn to wordpress and now I am able to get access token via REST API.

But Now I am getting issue job list. I want to get Jobs from a particular category only and here is my query for this

```
$method = 'query/JobOrder?BhRestToken='.$_SESSION['BH']['restToken'].'&where=publishedCategory = "IT"'&fields='.$fields.'&count='.$count;
    $response = makeHttpRequest($_SESSION['BH']['restURL'], $method);
```

and I not getting any jobs it takes category name as invalid field.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have a problem with your string, you should remove the `'` right after `publishedCategory = "IT"` - check the syntax higlighting

Comment: Thanks Vard. But I am getting same response even after removing `'`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things here. Your where clause should have

```
where=publishedCategory.name = 'IT'
```

You need single quotes and to specify the field that you are querying on for the category.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This query works for jobs with single categories.  It however doesn't work if a job belongs to multiple categories.  Do you know the query for the latter?